# automatic form submission with CURL php

Tags: php, curl

I can not run this script, I have every time two error messages can you help me

> (!) Warning: DOMDocument :: loadHTML (): Empty string Supplied as
>   input in C: \ wamp \ www \ form \ formulaire.php on line 23
>   0.1442 2 142344 loadHTML () .. \ formulaire.php: 23 Notice (!): Undefined variable: description in C: \ wamp \ www \ form \
>   formulaire.php on line 57

```
<?php
//La page qu'on veut utiliser
$wikipediaURL = 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth';
//On initialise cURL
$ch = curl_init();
//On lui transmet la variable qui contient l'URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $wikipediaURL);
//On lui demdande de nous retourner la page
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//On envoie un user-agent pour ne pas être considéré comme un bot malicieux
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Le blog de Samy Dindane (www.dinduks.com');
//On exécute notre requête et met le résultat dans une variable
$resultat = curl_exec($ch);
//On ferme la connexion cURL
curl_close($ch);
//On crée un nouveau document DOMDocument
$wikipediaPage = new DOMDocument();
//On y charge le contenu qu'on a récupéré avec cURL

$wikipediaPage->loadHTML($resultat);
//On parcourt les balises <div>
foreach($wikipediaPage->getElementsByTagName('div') as $div){
//Si l'id de la page est bodyContent
if($div->getAttribute('id') == "bodyContent"){
    //On met le contenu du premier <p> dans une variable
    $premierP = trim($div->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue);
    //Si le premier <p> est vide ou ne contient pas du texte
    while($premierP == '<br>' || $premierP == '<br />' || $premierP == ''){
        //On le supprime
        $div->removeChild($div->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0));
        //Et on passe au <p> suivant
        $premierP =   trim($div->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue);
        };

        //Un joli try pour éviter les messages d'erreur
    try{
        //On parcourt toutes les tables
        foreach( $div->getElementsByTagName('table') as $table ){
            //Et on les supprime
            $div->removeChild($table);
        }
    } catch(Exception $e){
        //On censure :P
    }

    //On récupère le contenu de la fameuse balise <p> dans une variable
    $description = '<p>' . $div->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue. '</p>';
}
}

//On enlève la syntaxe propre à Wikipedia
$description = preg_replace('/\[[0-9]*\][,]|\[[0-9]*\]/', '', $description);

//On affiche de résultat
echo $description;

?>

Hello I tackled too big so I gave up Thanks for your help
```

Comment: Which is line:57 in your code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [Simple Html Dom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). It really simplifies finding stuff in html files. Here is an example with your code.

```
<?php

include("simple_html_dom.php");

$wikipediaURL = 'http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth';
$html = file_get_html($wikipediaURL);
$description = '<p>' .$html->find('p', 0). '</p>';
$description = preg_replace('/\[[0-9]*\][,]|\[[0-9]*\]/', '', $description);
echo $description;
```

[Simple Html Dom Documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$resultat = file_get_contents('http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeth');
```